# How do I create an object from a derived class in Junit for testing

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I am trying to setup Junit, but just can't seem to, primarily because my use case is not basic (tho my skill level is).

I was given a jar as part of an assignment, and I can run the program without issue. However, I am unable to set it up properly in eclipse, such that it runs. The main method is in the jar package, so I cannot see it to give more information about it.

Here is my derived class that I would like to test.

```
package jimmy.kilmer.com;

import java.awt.Color;


import jarPackageImports.AI;
import jarPackageImports.MovementAction;
import jarPackageImports.GameInfo;
import jarPackageImports.PlayerAction;

public class GameAI extends AI {

    public gameAI(Info info) {
        super(info);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return Color.MAGENTA;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Usain Bolt";
    }

    public PlayerAction update() {

        // TODO game movement actions
        // all available methods not listed here...
        info.getVelocity();
        info.getX();
        info.getY();


    MovementAction steeringBehavior = null;

        return steeringBehavior;
    }
    
public int[][] populateAllPossibleNodes() {
        int[][] allPossibleNodes = new int[screenWidth/20][screenHeight/20];
        return allPossibleNodes;
    }
}
```

I have tried various different ways to instantiate an object in junit for it to run, but I simply cannot, and thus I can only test static method -- which isn't so useful.

This is what the template looks like.

```
package jimmy.kilmer.com;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class GameKITest {

    private Info info;

    private GameAI gameAiInstance = new GameAI((jarPackageImports.Info) Info info);

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

        @Test
    void testPopulateAllPossibleNodes() {
        // 1. given/arrange
        int[][] array1 = new int[80][65];
        // 2. when/act
        int[][] array2 = GameAiInstance.populateAllPossibleNodes();
        // 3. then/assert
        assertArrayEquals(array1, array2);
    }

}
```

There is something unbasic about the jar setup, such that I cannot simply create an object, the Info, which I don't have more information about, seems to be the problem. I thought it was a type of Java type? But, I couldn't find anything, so it must be a user create/enumerated type.

Any help to be able to develop this code in a TDD way, instead of just hacking in the derived class is my goal.

The above code will compile (not have errors in eclipse), but it returns NullPointerException: cannot invoke "jarPackageImports.Info.getScene()" because "this.info" is null.

If my understanding is correct, that means that I am not passing or setting up the info variable as it's supposed to be.

Comment: "I have tried various different ways to instantiate an object in junit for it to run, but I simply cannot" as we don't know what you tried, and what didn't work, we can't help.

Comment: None of the code shows an attempt to instantiate the class - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to use an instance of your Class you want to test.

```
package jimmy.kilmer.com;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class GameKITest {

   private GameKI gameKi = new GameKI(new Info());

   @Test
   void getName() {
             String actual = gameKi.getName();
             assertEquals("Usain Bolt", actual);
   }
 }
```

If you can not create an instance of needed dependencies, you could mock It by Mockito.

```
package jimmy.kilmer.com;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GameKITest {

   @Mock
   private Info info;

   private GameKI gameKi = new GameKI(info);

   @Test
   void getName() {

             Mock.when(info.getVelocity()).thenReturn(result);
             String actual = gameKi.update();
             assertEquals("Usain Bolt", actual);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Katt, unfortunately it did not work. I edited my last attempted code above in the post.

Comment: Your Code example is missing to much details. Therefore I could only show you some examples..

Comment: Thank you nevertheless, the examples, gave me more ideas of what I could try. If the class that I wanted to test had only static methods, it would be straightforward. I do not understand how the super(info) works in the constructor, and how to implement that properly in the junit test case. Mockito might be better at that? I am not familiar with it